# How many modules are there in Spring? What are they?

Tags: spring, module, count

just i want to know How many modules are there in Spring? What are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am working on `Spring Framework` from last `4+ years` now and I worked on most of the modules. Here is the list/names of the modules that I know:

```
1) Spring MVC
2) Spring Core
3) Spring REST
4) Spring Boot
5) Spring JDBCTemplates
6) Spring XD
7) Spring Grails
8) Spring Batch
9) Spring Roo
10) Spring Security
11) Spring Data JPA (Hibernate)
12) Spring Data Mongo (MongoDB,Couchbase etc..)
13) Spring Groovy
14) Spring Reactor
15) Spring WebFlow
16) Spring Transaction
17) Spring AOP
18) Spring WebFlow
19) Spring Remote Services
20) Messaging in Spring
21) Sending Emails with Spring
etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by modules? This is the [list](http://www.springsource.org/projects/) of projects in SpringSource. The main Spring Framework has many [features](http://www.springsource.org/about), which are independent to each other.